# How to create customize menu structure in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

first wrote Custom template context processor method

```
def show_pages_menu(context):


    pages_menu= suppliers.objects.filter(show_in_menu=True)

    return {'pages_menu': pages_menu}
```

after i added this method to my settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'Accounts.pages_context.show_pages_menu'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

at the end i had created template menu.html

```
{# First render the pages #}
{% for page in pages_menu %}

{# Then check if current page is 'published' #}
{% if page.status == 'published' %}

<li>
  <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{page.menu_title}}</a>
</li>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And added this url in my urls.py

```
url(r'^suppliers/', CreateView.as_view(), name="suppliers")
```

i had follow [this](http://kkabardi.me/post/dynamic-menu-navigation-django/) tutorial.But i am getting error

> Cannot resolve keyword 'show_in_menu' into field.

Comment: Did you double checked that your suppliers model has the field "show_in_menu"?

Comment: Please add your suppliers model.

Comment: yes i had added supplier model.

Comment: i have no field show_in_menu @DiogoRosa do i need to add it ?

Comment: @HassanALi yes you do my friend. Don't get me wrong but you seem pretty new to django, you should check some tutorial and really get into the framework before you start asking this basic questions. Anyway let me know if you need further help :)!